# any method to find instance of given Object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any new method or approach to find the instance ( parent Object class name) in es6?

just like we have `typeof <entity>` and it returns the type

and the `keyof` in typescript

can we check somehow that this is the instance of which Object?

#### dummy code

`instanceof <entity>`

return something like that

1. HTTPError
2. HTMLElement
3. NodeList
4. undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the object's `constructor` property (which is usually inherited from its prototype) if the object in question has one (not all will; ones created via constructor functions usually will).

Example:

```js
const dt = new Date();
console.log(dt.constructor === Date); // true
```

For instance, in ES2015+, `Promise`, `Array`, and others use `constructor` when creating new objects of the same type (for instance, `Promise`'s `then` uses it, `Array`'s `slice` uses it, etc.) so that those operations are friendly to subclasses. Gratuitous subclass example:

```js
class MyArray extends Array {
}
const a = new MyArray("a", "b", "c");
const b = a.slice(1);              // Creates new MyArray
console.log(b.join(", "));         // "b, c"
console.log(b instanceof MyArray); // true
```

**In general**, though, in JavaScript we tend to prefer [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) to `constructor` or `instanceof` checks.

Comment: my question is what if I don't know the `instance of` which this belongs to?

Comment: @pro.mean - Right, that's `.constructor`. It gives you the function that's associated with the object as its constructor. You don't have to have pre-existing knowledge of the function. (And if you want its *name*, on ES2015+ engines, use its `.name` property: `console.log(obj.constructor.name);`.)

Comment: Thank you, magician. that is my desired answer moreover the main answer is wider and in depth. thanks for the concise detail.